# Maven dependency with old version

Tags: java, maven

I need to compile a project with this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wadpam</groupId>
    <artifactId>docrest-doclet</artifactId>
    <version>1.21</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

(and a lot more like this)

In public maven repositories there's no version 1.21 the oldest one is 1.22. Where can I find that jar?

Comment: why do you want to continue using outdated libraries?

Comment: @Stultuske Perhaps recent libraries are not compatibles.

Comment: I want to compile with outdated libraries first, and then upgrade it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and built it from source from this github repo:

https://github.com/sosandstrom/docrest

From the command line you can do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/sosandstrom/docrest.git
cd docrest
git checkout docrest-1.21
```

Comment: So he has to compile the dependency himself?

Comment: I can't find it in Maven Central or the JBoss Maven repository, so I guess this is the only way

Comment: Well it works on your computer because the mvn clean install will put the finalized dependency in your local maven repository. The build is still not going to work anywhere else, or after you delete you .m2 directory because then Maven will have to try and find it online again. Keep that in mind. It would be more portable to use something like the addjars plugin: https://code.google.com/p/addjars-maven-plugin/wiki/UsagePage

Comment: I know, I can deploy these artifacts in a private nexus server to share with my team. But what I need to do now is write unit tests and upgrade versions to latest ones.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do it is creating [jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies). It was described also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)